# Getting Mbed Nucleo F401RE to work with LCD TFT HX8347

Tags: c++, screen, lcd, mbed

I am quite new to this.

I have a 2.8" TFT LCD (HX8347) screen and currently trying to get it working with my Nucleo F401RE.

I imported the library located here: https://developer.mbed.org/users/Suky/code/LCDTFT/

I deleted the code to draw images (don't need it and it was throwing an error).

The problem is it looks like the example code uses a different set of definitions for the pins

```
#include "mbed.h"
#include "LCDTFT.h"

BusOut  MyBus(p13,p14,p15,p16,p17,p18,p19,p20,p30,p29,p28,p27,p26,p25,p24,p23);
LCDTFT  MyLCD(p5,p6,p7,p22,p21,&MyBus);
```

This throws an error as the "p" values don't exist. So I figured they are "D0", "D1", ... . But I am not sure at all, even what sort of mapping, (it goes to 30??).

Answer (score 1):

## Some Research

The {p13,p14,p15...} names are coming from the PinNames.h file.

For reference, you can see how they are defined for the popular LPC1768 board:

```
// mbed DIP Pin Names
p5 = P0_9,
p6 = P0_8,
p7 = P0_7,
p8 = P0_6,
```

For the NUCLEO_F401RE {p1,p2,...} aren't defined but {PA_0,PA_1,...} are.

```
PA_0  = 0x00,
PA_1  = 0x01,
PA_2  = 0x02,
PA_3  = 0x03,
```

## Solution

You need to state the correct pin names on your own.

The LCDFT constructor from the library header file:

```
LCDTFT(PinName PIN_RD,PinName PIN_WR,PinName PIN_RS,PinName PIN_CS,PinName PIN_RESET, BusOut *BUSLCD);
```

The following diagram shows you how the LCD display should be connected:
[LCD connectivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRD6E.png)

The following diagram lists the available pins on your board:
[Board pinout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLkij.png)

#### This is the connectivity you should use

PIN_RD <--> mosi <--> PA_7

PIN_WR <--> miso <--> PA_6

PIN_RS <--> sck <--> PA_5

PIN_CS <--> PwmOut <--> PA_0

PIN_RESET <--> PwmOut <--> PA_1

BusOut: This can be any free output pins that you've got, so.

## Finally

```
#include "mbed.h"
#include "LCDTFT.h"

BusOut  MyBus(A2,A3,A4,A5,D0,D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7,D8,D9,D10,D14,D15);
LCDTFT  MyLCD(PA_7,PA_6,PA_5,PA_0,PA_1,&MyBus);
```

Hope this works for you!